# Firebase firestore transactions and threading - python

Tags: python, multithreading, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a python script, which is based on the examples given here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Namely:

```
transaction = db.transaction()
city_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

@firestore.transactional
def update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref):
    snapshot = city_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
    transaction.update(city_ref, {
        u'population': snapshot.get(u'population') + 1
    })

update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref)
```

I can't find any good documentation on what the transactional decorator does in detail (other than mark what should be executed in the transaction), but it seems whenever I try to make the call from a new thread, it seizes up and I haven't been able to come up with an explanation:

```
   //Works fine if called like this
   update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref)

   //Does NOT work if called like this:
   threading.Thread(target=self.__my_method_to_start_the_transaction)
```

It's problematic, since it is blocking my UI thread and I can't render any loading indicators, etc. Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little code to check what could be going on with the sample data from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import threading

db = firestore.Client()
transaction = db.transaction()

city_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'LA')

@firestore.transactional
def update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref):
    snapshot = city_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
    transaction.update(city_ref, {
        u'population': snapshot.get(u'population') + 1
    })


x = threading.Thread(target=update_in_transaction, args=(transaction, city_ref))
x.start()
```

And it worked as expected. In your code I think you have a more complex workflow and maybe there could be missing something. Anyway if you want more details about the decorator, here is the code for the decorator [`transactional`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/firestore_v1/transaction.html#transactional) which at the same time calls the method [`_Transactional`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/firestore_v1/transaction.html#_Transactional).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'd almost given up hope on this, yes - back to basics helped in getting to the root of the problem, I essentially had a race condition in my code which meant that the listener wasn't setup at the time the transaction was being sent out. Thank you!